# "404" error while uploading large file (>150mb) in laravel 5.7 on godaddy server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm facing one problem during upload of large file (>150mb) through post request in laravel 5.7 on godaddy server.

Small files (<150mb) I can upload but large files i can't while i can upload large files in localhost. On server when I'm trying to upload large file during form submission the page is redirecting to the route path and displaying "404" error.

I have also updated the values of upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, memory_limit upto 2G on server but its not working for me. I have attached the screenshot of error:

[image]

Comment: Have your tried restarting your server after updating the values?

Comment: create a new php file in laravel public directory e.g.: info.php which contains phpinfo() func.: <?php phpinfo(); ?>. Call this file from browser to check php options are really changed to what you set

Comment: Hi @Jakob L, Thanks for the reply. I have updated those values through php.in. So, do you think I should to restart the server? While the new values are already displaying in phpinfo().

Comment: its strange that you are seeing a 404, which means resource isn't found (nothing to do with file sizes) I'd open the inspect (f12) in the browser and see what exactly is being sent and returned. the 404 is response to what exactly? are you using a browser with an upload form in js? maybe try postman?

Comment: Hi @NiRR, Nope. I'm not using any js or ajax request. I'm uploading file through POST request. Using same form and same route I can upload small files but large files i can't.